# SQL Server: Is it worth placing BLOB/CLOB columns near the "end" of a table?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, database-schema

Is is an urban legend or having BLOB/CLOB columns last in a list of columns in a table really benefits performance and other aspects?

To "visualise". Is there any difference performance-wise (and *other-* wise) between these two table layouts:

```
A                            B
---------------------        ---------------------
ID      int                  ID      int
Name    nvarchar(200)        Content nvarchar(max)
Content nvarchar(max)        Name    nvarchar(200)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818/sql-server-does-column-order-matter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance / Space implications when ordering SQL Server columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692021/performance-space-implications-when-ordering-sql-server-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's an urban legend

On-disk layout is completely independent of the ordering of columns in the CREATE table. See this for more
[Performance / Space implications when ordering SQL Server columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692021/performance-space-implications-when-ordering-sql-server-columns/6692107#6692107)

Note: whether a varchar column is at the "start" or the "end", SQL Server still reads it the [same via an offset from the NULL bitmap.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/29/650349.aspx) The MAX column may be in the record or in another page if too long. SO still doesn't matter

There was an issue years ago (pre-dot net) with some SQL Server client drivers that preferred large text parameters at the end. Ancient myths.

Comment: @Anton Gogolev: done for on-disk structures. It's in MSDN too. Can't find anything on the other bit because there is no online information for SQL Server 6.5 nowadays