# Adding column between two other columns in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

Can you add a column to a table inserting it in between two existing columns in SQL Server without dropping and re-creating the table?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610/can-i-logically-reorder-columns-in-a-table and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402312/why-cant-i-reorder-my-sql-server-columns

Comment: take table design and just drag the column accordingly

Comment: @Athul Suresh this solution may not work depending on your SQL Server configuration. I received an error stating I need to enable saving changes that require dropping and rebuilding the table. It could also create a permission issue for some.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple answer is no. Is there a reason why column order is important to you?

Comment: not really, I was going through a tutorial that asked me to do so.  I didn't bother because it's functionally useless, it just piqued my interest.

Answer (score 11):

Mediumly long answer, yes (ish) but it's ugly and you probably wouldn't want to do it.

*please note: this code creates a physical table*

```
CREATE TABLE MyTest (a int, b int, d int, e int)

INSERT INTO MyTest (a,b,d,e) VALUES(1,2,4,5)

SELECT * FROM MyTest

ALTER TABLE MyTest ADD c int
ALTER TABLE MyTest ADD d_new int
ALTER TABLE MyTest ADD e_new int

UPDATE MyTest SET d_new = d, e_new = e

ALTER TABLE MyTest DROP COLUMN d
ALTER TABLE MyTest DROP COLUMN e

EXEC SP_RENAME 'MyTest.d_new', 'd';
EXEC SP_RENAME 'MyTest.e_new', 'e';

SELECT * FROM MyTest 

DROP TABLE MyTest
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can add here is the query for your concern:

```
ALTER table table_name ADD column column_name(new) datatype AFTER column_name
```

Comment: Your answer is for MySQL. They're asking about SQL Server.

Comment: well, still thankful for this, I need this'

Comment: This worked well for MariaDB

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this link:

http://www.bobsgear.com/display/ts/Adding+Column+After+Another+Column+-+SQL+Server+2005

As you can see, the answer is:

*'not possible without moving data to a temp table'*

which is what the **SQL Server Management Studio** actually does.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

yes.  You can drag and drop it in design mode, or copy and paste it in edit table mode

---

in response to comments, yes, this is with SQL Server Management Studio through the UI, and under the hood, it's doing the drop/recreate you're trying to avoid, so no, you can't do it without the server doing it for you.

Comment: That will do a drop/recreate in the background.

Comment: I am assuming this is what you would do if you were using SQL Management Studio.  Are you sure that SQL Server doesn't do a drop and re-create behind the scenes.  I have got a feeling it copies the data to a temp table and then drops and recreates the table before copying the data back.  I don't have access to SQL Server right now or I'd fire up SQL Profiler and try what you suggested.

Comment: i was really looking for a way to do it in the ALTER TABLE statement, which is what SQL Management Studio does anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).
Filter your table in Object Explorer and right click on the table > Design

[image]

Drag the arrow highlighted in the left to move your column.

Answer (score 0):

First answer, no.

Second answer, according to this thread http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=58912, found via [Can I logically reorder columns in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610/can-i-logically-reorder-columns-in-a-table), you could create the column then reorder the columns in the table by editing the system tables.  But it looks incredibly messy and I would not trust that things would not break.

Comment: You cannot edit the system tables in versions after SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

For Mysql yes For SQL server No
also it's not a good practice to add column in between as it can hamper some queries if you are relying on the table schema in your project.