# How to add column in between two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a column in between columns and getting the following error:

> Msg 259, Level 16, State 1, Line 10: 
>   Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

This is what I have done:

```
select * from 
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'Customers' 

Alter table Customers  
Add ContactName varchar(20)

Update INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
set ORDINAL_POSITION = 3
where  TABLE_NAME = 'Customers ' and COLUMN_NAME = 'ContactName'
```

The column should move to the third position.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5327545/4524485

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding column between two other columns in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327545/adding-column-between-two-other-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: Pls pay attention when you tag your question, incorrect tagging (MySQL instead of sql-server) caused two users two post answers that are not useful to you and wasted their time.

Comment: You don't directly modify the system tables/views - EVER.

Comment: And learn to search the internet for any error messages you encounter. You're not the first to try this hack and the solution is always the same - recreate the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Alter table Customers  
Add ContactName varchar(20)  AFTER `columnthatisprevioustoadded`
```

Comment: The question was incorrectly labelled as MySQL, it is related to ms sql server (see the error message and the [...]). If it was related to MySQL, then it were a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Alter command by default create column at the end of the table

```
 Alter table Customers  
Add ContactName varchar(20)
```

You need to use `AFTER` which place a column in a certain position

```
Alter table Customers  
Add ContactName varchar(20) after column_name_exist_in_position2
```

column_name_exist_in_position2 = your table 2nd position column name

Comment: @MdMerajAlam here is the online demo https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=74b125221cfd674943301b5cdb64e735 check it

Comment: The question was incorrectly labelled as MySQL, it is related to ms sql server (see the error message and the [...]). If it was related to MySQL, then it were a duplicate.